# Help me find a story where your consciousness can travel in time via use of drugs?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read a novel about 15 years ago, with time-traveling as the main topic. People can send their current consciousness to the past or the future inside them, with 2 kind of drugs respectively. With the future there were no problems, but when they change the past in the present you can ride down the road and see a bridge with sign "Bridge exists with probability 0.5".

Can someone remember this novel?

Comment: Is this Dune or one of its sequels?

Comment: "Now Wait for Last Year"?

Comment: @DVK,"Now Wait for Last Year" - no, all actions performed during our timeline or near-future and "close-to-reality" setting. Basically it's not fiction with imaginative Universe or far-future setting...

Comment: And it's not: "An Age" by Brian Aldiss, "The House on the Strand" by Daphne du Maurier or "A Quantum Murder" by Greg Mandel

Comment: @b_jonas, definitely not Dune series

Comment: Could it be [ARC Riders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Drake#ARC_Riders)?

Comment: @bitmask No, plot sounds more like alternative history.

Comment: " "A Quantum Murder" by Greg Mandel " That's the name of the main character, not the author, Peter Hamilton.

Answer (score 2):

There is something similar to this concept on "Flow My Tears, the Policeman Said" by k dick but i'm not sure if it is the same

Comment: That was my first thought as well, after reading the title and first sentence.  However, none of the rest of the details seem to match.

Comment: @Pelirrojilla,@Beofett Sorry, not this one. In a story I'm trying to find, they are can go both ways, into the past and the future. I recall there was a young woman and a friend of protagonist, which tried to help him stop using drugs. But I don't remember finale...